# How to remove blank space at the bottom of the page that's caused by a button?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

so i already know the cause of the blank space at the bottom of my page and it's a sticky "back to top" button, but i don't know how to fix it.

here's the page layout

```
<nav>
  navbar
</nav>
<div>
  caroussel
</div>
<div>
  some images
</div>

    <!--Back to top button-->

<button onclick="to_top()" id="top_btn">
  <img src="Icons/uparrow.png" id="top_ico">
</button>
<div>
 footer
</div>
```

the css

```
#top_btn 
{
    --offset: 50px; 
    position: sticky;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 15px;
    bottom: 20px;      
    place-self: end;
    margin-top: calc(100vh + var(--offset));
    padding: 10px;
    background: #013328;
    color: #e3dcd2;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 9px #666;
}

#top_ico
{
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

  
#top_btn:hover 
{
    background-color: #013328;
}
  
#top_btn:active 
{
    background-color: #013328;
    box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
    transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

script

```
function to_top() 
{
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; 
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

i've tried changing the button from sticky to fixed and it worked but it also ruined the style i'm going for where the button remains hidden in sticky position until the user scrolls down a bit then it remains sticky at bottom right corner of the screen.

thank you all in advance

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure if I understood correctly what the problem is but try putting the position to fixed and add to your #top_btn right: 0;

Hopefully this solves your problem :)

Comment: If you are not sure what the problem is, request clarification from the OP. Don't post an answer. Once you will have sufficient reputation, you will be able to use the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) section.